# Need to change this query by using joins

Tags: mysql

I need to change my Mysql old Query to use join instead of using old format, Currently the issue in my query is that its getting the more than 1000 repeated results actual number of rows that should returned is 4 I have tried many things but did not get any luck. Here is my Query

```
SELECT pc.* 
FROM product_cache pc 
WHERE pc.category = 'Connectors' 
    AND (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM product_attr_cache 
                WHERE product_cache_id = pc.id AND name = 'series' AND value = 'SMA')) 
    AND (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM product_attr_cache 
                WHERE product_cache_id = pc.id AND name = 'orientation' AND value = 'Straight')) 
    AND (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM product_attr_cache 
                WHERE product_cache_id = pc.id AND name = 'connection' AND value = 'Male') 
        OR EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM product_attr_cache 
                WHERE product_cache_id = pc.id AND name = 'connection' AND value = 'Plug')) 
    AND (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM product_attr_cache 
                WHERE product_cache_id = pc.id AND name = 'mount' AND value = '2 Hole Flange')) 
    AND (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM product_attr_cache 
                WHERE product_cache_id = pc.id AND name = 'termination' AND value = 'Receptacle-Solder'))
```

Comment: Please format the code properly.  No one will read long, one-liner code.

Comment: That details what you have to convert, can you please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi Mr Slim,

I have tried this but its giving me empty rows without any results

Comment: SELECT * FROM product_cache pc  JOIN product_attr_cache ON pc.category = 'Connectors' 
AND product_cache_id = pc.id AND name = 'series' AND value = 'SMA' AND product_cache_id = pc.id AND name = 'orientation' AND value = 'Straight' AND product_cache_id = pc.id AND name = 'connection' AND value = 'Male' OR product_cache_id = pc.id AND name = 'connection' AND value = 'Plug' AND product_cache_id = pc.id AND name = 'mount' AND value = '2 Hole Flange' AND product_cache_id = pc.id AND name = 'termination' AND value = 'Receptacle-Solder'

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove all the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Distinct to avoid duplicate data.

```
> SELECT distinct pc.*  FROM product_cache pc  WHERE pc.category =
> 'Connectors' 
>     AND (EXISTS (SELECT * 
>                 FROM product_attr_cache 
>                 WHERE product_cache_id = pc.id AND name = 'series' AND value = 'SMA')) 
>     AND (EXISTS (SELECT * 
>                 FROM product_attr_cache 
>                 WHERE product_cache_id = pc.id AND name = 'orientation' AND value = 'Straight')) 
>     AND (EXISTS (SELECT * 
>                 FROM product_attr_cache 
>                 WHERE product_cache_id = pc.id AND name = 'connection' AND value = 'Male') 
>         OR EXISTS (SELECT * 
>                 FROM product_attr_cache 
>                 WHERE product_cache_id = pc.id AND name = 'connection' AND value = 'Plug')) 
>     AND (EXISTS (SELECT * 
>                 FROM product_attr_cache 
>                 WHERE product_cache_id = pc.id AND name = 'mount' AND value = '2 Hole Flange')) 
>     AND (EXISTS (SELECT * 
>                 FROM product_attr_cache 
>                 WHERE product_cache_id = pc.id AND name = 'termination' AND value = 'Receptacle-Solder'))
```